# Ubuntu: Rails installation requires Ruby =>1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I'm having touble installing rails on my new installation of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have RVM and rubygems 2.2.2 installed but when I go to install rails I get an error;

```
anesu@ubuntu:~$ gem install rails
[sudo] password for anesu: #I enter my passsword here
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
anesu@ubuntu:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24 revision 45159) [x86_64-linux]
```

The ruby required is clearly installed. I've also tried

```
gem install rails #without sudo
```

but still get the same error. What could be the problem?

Comment: What do you get if you enter `sudo ruby -v`?

Comment: Are you *sure* you are using your RVM installation?

Comment: please dont install gems from root user, use instead rvm/rbenv instead

Comment: @lurker 'sudo ruby -v' returns 'ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]'

Comment: Therein lies the issue. When you do your `gem install` and it's asking for the password, it's installing as `root` and `root` sees version 1.8.7. As @МалъСкрылевъ suggests, `rvm` is highly recommended.

Comment: @Mark Thomas I ran 'rvm use ruby-1.9.3' and I also ran 'rvm --default use ruby-1.9.3'..is that okay?

Comment: So how do I get around this problem @lurker? I'm completely new to Ubuntu.

Comment: What is the output of rvm list?

Comment: If `rvm` is installed correctly, it shouldn't be prompting you for a password when you install a gem. You may need to go back and redo your `rvm` installation per the specific instructions given on their website.

Comment: @Arkash 'anesu@ubuntu:~$ rvm list

rvm rubies

 * ruby-1.9.3-p545 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default'

Comment: @yaboiduke provide please `which rvm`

Comment: @Малъ Скрылевъ - rvm 1.25.22 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

Comment: @yaboiduke no, that is not result for `which rvm`. is should be a path

Comment: The tutorial [Install Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html) is helpful.

Comment: Just an FYI: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is scheduled to be released in 2 days. In any case, if you are planning to use RVM, I would NOT install native ruby packages, and rely instead on RVM to manage all your Ruby environments. Alternatively, use [chruby](http://zaiste.net/2013/04/towards_simplicity_from_rbenv_to_chruby/).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have rvm in your path? If not, add the following line to your ~.bashrc file...

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin
```

Be sure and open and close the terminal after you all this. At the terminal you should be able to type 'echo $PATH' and see RVM listed.